# Sum across multple columns and rows in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which has duplicate column names and multiple duplicate row names. I would like to condense the matrix to a single column name and single row num but with the sum from all the cells that match that criteria. I have tried different combinations of sumifs with index, match, match as well as sumproduct() but nothing is working as expected. I feel that there is some other functions that I could be trying (especially with filter()) but I'm not sure. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!
[image]

sumifs with index match, match & sumproduct()

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but a summation of different currencies into a single sum would require you to keep in mind exchange rates of these currencies, no? Is the single summation in Dollars for example? If not relevant, then maybe leave out this detail as it seems likely to throw more questions.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. So the column with currencies is dynamic as it can change from month to month.

Comment: Instead of SUM, SUM, SUM, why don't you show us the exact result for e.g. `Product1` and `Product2`?

Comment: @MV914, you have not addressed my question at all. You just said the data is dynamic which is totally not my point =). Sidenote, if you want any help with this at all, I'd suggest to use markdown sample data to make it easy for users to copy/paste the data.

Comment: I would be looking at sumifs().

Comment: How could you possibly add different currencies? Makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Barring the obvious issue with simply adding together multiple currencies, this is the formula I believe you're looking for (for cell B27):

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$6:$A$23=$A27)*($B$4:$H$4=B$26)*($B$6:$H$23))`